# how to translat a variable in magento 2

Tags: magento2

in my case i use translation in magento 2 , all the string text to be translated works fine, but when i want to translate a variable i can't get the translation , can anyone tell me why ?

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($var->getData()['colomn'])) ?>
```

output

```
"text"
```

translat file

```
"text","text translate"
```

> why i can't get "text translate" instead of "processing" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below way to translate the variable.

```
<?= __($block->escapeHtml($var->getData()['column'])) ?>
```

Also, please add the module name in your translation file like below.

```
"processing","En cours de traitement",module,Magento_Sales
```

or

```
"processing","En cours de traitement",module,Magento_Theme
```

Reference: https://alanstorm.com/magento-2-translation-function-not-sprintf/

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: thank you  for your response but it's not working i don't know why !?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache after changes?

Comment: yes and upgrading also

Comment: anyway it works for by doing this , <?= __($block->escapeHtml($var->getData()['column'])) ?>

Answer (score 0):

anyway it works for by doing this ,

```
<?= __($block->escapeHtml($var->getData()['column'])) ?>
```